# How to replace "array elements" of a numpy.ndarray with respect to a condition without using explicit loops?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, performance

I have a three dimensional `numpy.ndarray` with shape (5, 4, 3) and I would like to replace some of the arrays with three elements inside my array by another one. For instance, I would like to replace all `[3, 3, 3]` elements by `[0, 0, 0]`.
Below, I present a solution I found but this solution is not efficient enough and can be really long on big arrays.

---

I have created the following `numpy.ndarray`:

```
c = np.array([[[3,3,3],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4]],[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[7,3,3],[4,4,4]],[[1,1,1],[3,3,3],[3,3,3],[4,4,4]],[[1,1,1],[2,2,2],[3,8,3],[3,3,3]],[[3,3,3],[2,2,2],[3,3,3],[4,4,4]]])
```

This gives me:

> >>> c
>
> ```
> array([[[3, 3, 3],
>         [2, 2, 2],
>         [3, 3, 3],
>         [4, 4, 4]],
>
>        [[1, 1, 1],
>         [2, 2, 2],
>         [7, 3, 3],
>         [4, 4, 4]],
>
>        [[1, 1, 1],
>         [3, 3, 3],
>         [3, 3, 3],
>         [4, 4, 4]],
>
>        [[1, 1, 1],
>         [2, 2, 2],
>         [3, 8, 3],
>         [3, 3, 3]],
>
>        [[3, 3, 3],
>         [2, 2, 2],
>         [3, 3, 3],
>         [4, 4, 4]]])
> ```
>
> >>> c.shape
>
> ```
>     (5, 4, 3)
> ```

I would like to replace all the elements `[3, 3, 3]` by `[0, 0, 0]`.

The solution I found is the following:

```
# I reshape my array to get only a 2D array
c_copy = c.reshape(c.shape[0] * c.shape[1], c.shape[2])

# Then I loop through all the elements of the array to replace [3, 3, 3] by [0, 0, 0]
c_copy[[np.array_equal(e, [3, 3, 3]) for e in c_copy]] = [0,0,0]

# And I reshape my copy to get the original shape back
c_modified = c_copy.reshape(c.shape)
```

This works well:

> >>> c_modified
>
> ```
> array([[[0, 0, 0],
>         [2, 2, 2],
>         [0, 0, 0],
>         [4, 4, 4]],
>
>        [[1, 1, 1],
>         [2, 2, 2],
>         [7, 3, 3],
>         [4, 4, 4]],
>
>        [[1, 1, 1],
>         [0, 0, 0],
>         [0, 0, 0],
>         [4, 4, 4]],
>
>        [[1, 1, 1],
>         [2, 2, 2],
>         [3, 8, 3],
>         [0, 0, 0]],
>
>        [[0, 0, 0],
>         [2, 2, 2],
>         [0, 0, 0],
>         [4, 4, 4]]])
> ```

However the loop `for e in c_copy` is killing me. This is fine for this small ndarray but I have an array of 9000000 elements and I haven't found any efficient solution.

What could I do to speed the computation?

---

[Live example](https://onlinegdb.com/1EDK4vXtk)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need find index of `[3,3,3]` for this you can use `all(axis=-1)`, then replace with `[0,0,0]`:

```
row, col = np.where((c==3).all(-1))
c[row, col] = [0,0,0]
print(c)
```

Output:

```
[[[0 0 0]
  [2 2 2]
  [0 0 0]
  [4 4 4]]

 [[1 1 1]
  [2 2 2]
  [7 3 3]
  [4 4 4]]

 [[1 1 1]
  [0 0 0]
  [0 0 0]
  [4 4 4]]

 [[1 1 1]
  [2 2 2]
  [3 8 3]
  [0 0 0]]

 [[0 0 0]
  [2 2 2]
  [0 0 0]
  [4 4 4]]]
```